# vlc 3.0 ./configure gives "Missing libav or FFmpeg" despite I have them

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, vlc, configure, libavcodec

I am trying to build the most recent development version of vlc-3.0 (git cloned) from source, but running `./configure` gives me the following error:

```
configure: error: Missing libav or FFmpeg
```

That is despite I have built from source and installed a fresh ffmpeg-3.2.2 with the following configuration including --enable-shared (see below). Also, in my /usr/lib directory there is a library libavcodec.a , libavcodec.so.57.64.101 with symbolic links to it libavcodec.so and libavcodec.so.57

Just looked at https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/master/configure.ac source code, it requires a libavcodec >=57.16.0 from libav or >=57.37.100 from ffmpeg, and 57.64.101 satisfies that requirement so still can't understand what is wrong.

**Maybe I need to pass some additional flag to vlc-3.0 to force it to notice my libavcodec library? If yes, what flags should I try?**

ffmpeg configure options (just in case):

```
--prefix=/usr --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --disable-libebur128 --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libopencv --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-chromaprint --enable-shared
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a really helpful advice from Rémi Denis-Courmont at VLC forums thread - https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=137096

```
Make sure that "pkg-config --modversion libavcodec" works.
If not, then FFmpeg is essentially not installed.
```

This command gave me the following error message:

```
Package libavcodec was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libavcodec.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libavcodec' found
```

Checked my PKG_CONFIG_PATH variable - it was empty :

```
echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

Then I searched at /usr directory for libavcodec.pc , and found it:

```
find /usr -name "libav*.pc"
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libavutil.pc
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libavcodec.pc
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libavfilter.pc
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libavformat.pc
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libavdevice.pc
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libavresample.pc
/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/libavc1394.pc
```

Now all I needed to do is to add these path: /usr/lib/pkgconfig/ , and also /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/ just in case, to PKG_CONFIG_PATH (could be done through bashrc or any other way). After that, "pkg-config --modversion libavcodec" outputs a version number of libavcodec instead of error, and vlc could be configured and built without any problems! ^_^

Comment: export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/:/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig/
 # export must be used!!!!